# How to analyse the convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I've tried to use the squeeze theorem and direct comparison test, but I've gotten nowhere.
I attempted to use $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$ to get to $-x^{-2} \leq \frac{\sin x}{x^2} \leq x^{-2}$, and then get $\int_0^\infty -\frac{1}{x^2} \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^2} dx \leq \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ but since the integrals in the edges don't exist I do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That integral diverges because, for some $a>0$, you have$$x\in(0,a]\implies\sin x>\frac x2\implies\frac{\sin x}{x^2}>\frac1{2x},$$and the integral $\int_0^a\frac1{2x}\mathrm dx$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

A variant with basic *asymptotic analysis*:

Near $0$, $\dfrac{\sin x}x\sim 1$, so
$$\frac{\sin x}{x^2}\sim_0\frac 1x,$$
which has a diverging integral. This works because  $\frac{\sin x}x >0$ on the interval $(0, a)$ if $a$ is small enough.

Comment: I would emphasiser that $\sin(x)/x>0$ near $0$ so that we can use comparison (I say that because OP overviewed this fact and used $\pm\frac 1{x^2}$).

Comment: @zwim: for me, it did go without saying, but you're  probably right. I'll add it within seconds. Thanks!